# How do I write insertionSort using foldr?

Tags: haskell

I wrote the following Haskell functions:

```
myInsert :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
myInsert x [] = [x]
myInsert x (y:ys) = if x < y then x:y:ys else y:myInsert x ys

insertionSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
insertionSort [] = []
insertionSort [x] = [x]
insertionSort (x:xs) = myInsert x (insertionSort xs)
```

As you can see, "insertionSort" depends on "myInsert", and they work fine. Now I am asked to use "foldr" in "insertioSort" but I have not been able to get a successful result.

I will appreciate your feedback.

Comment: The implementation you show here isn't really relevant; your question is really just "How do I write `insertionSort` using `foldr`?"

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [definition of `foldr` used in GHC](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr):

```
foldr k z = go
          where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

Just for simplicity, let's inline `go`, and use a bit less fancy syntax:

```
foldr k z [] = z
foldr k z (x:xs) = k x (foldr k z xs)
```

For comparison, here is your function:

```
insertionSort [] = []
insertionSort (x:xs) = myInsert x (insertionSort xs)
```

Notice how similar they are! Can you figure out what `k` and `z` would need to be in the `foldr` equations to be equal to your implementation of `insertionSort`?